# Database trigger problem with conditional update

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, triggers

I want to correct a value after a dataset is inserted into a table. I tried to solve this using a database trigger. But it's not working any more if I add conditions to the update call.

This code is working so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgValidateQuantityUnit
    ON  dbo.tblPart AFTER INSERT

AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    UPDATE tblPart SET tblPart.description3='TEST'
    FROM tblPart INNER JOIN inserted ON (tblPart.id = inserted.id);

END
GO
```

it does not change the data any more. If a change the update query to this:

```
UPDATE tblPart SET tblPart.description3='TEST'
FROM tblPart INNER JOIN inserted ON (tblPart.id = inserted.id)
WHERE (tblPart.craftelectro<>0);
```

I also tried

```
UPDATE tblPart SET tblPart.description3='TEST'
FROM tblPart INNER JOIN inserted ON (tblPart.id = inserted.id)
AND (tblPart.craftelectro<>0);
```

Can somebody point me to the right direction please?

EDIT:
the purpose of the trigger should be, to bring the quantityunit (in the sampledata below) to the same format. e.g. not empty, uppercase. the quantityunit is determined by some other fields like productgroup, craftelectro ...

```
quantityunit            |craftelectro|productgroup
__________________________________________________
??_??@M;                |           1|  29
de_DE@M;en_EN@M;en_US@M;|           1|  29
??_??@m;                |           1|  29
                        |           1|  29
```

Comment: i believe what you want is `WHERE (inserted.craftelectro<>0)`

Comment: no unfurtonately still not working

Comment: perhaps you can show us some sample data and the expected result so that we can have an clear understanding on what you are trying to achieve. As it is, we are all guessing

Comment: added some sample data, i hope it's a bit clearer, what i want to do. the description3 field is just for testing because it's usually empty

Comment: this trigger looks fine. Do  you have any other trigger for this table ?

Comment: no other triggers in the whole database

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your code as this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trgValidateQuantityUnit
    ON  dbo.tblPart 
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE T
    SET    description3='TEST'
    FROM   tblPart AS T
           INNER JOIN inserted AS i
              ON T.id = i.id;
END
GO
```

Comment: Hi, this code is working but it stops working if i add an additional condition like `WHERE (i.craftelectro<>0);`

Comment: @Andreas Are you sure that craftelectro contains a NON NULL value ?

Comment: it is defined as craftelectro(bit, not NULL)